# "Timebase not supported by MPEG 4 Standard" Error when rendering AVI/MPEG-4 video

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image: Error Message]

I've been trying to render a video but either it won't have sound or it won't have audio. Whenever I try to render it in a way I can get both video and audio, this error message shows up. Any idea whats causing this?

my render settings:
[image: Render Settings]

Comment: try File -> Load Factory Settings and adding the most basic animation with sound and seeing it that renders correctly. If it does then there is some setting that is out of place in your current file.

Comment: @rob unfortunately it doesnt, sound is the only thing that renders and video remains black, even with factory settings

Comment: What if you just render the default Cube as a single frame, default Cube as an animation but with no changes per frame. Same but with an audio file that you have tested in the Video Sequence Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Avi (divx) oh shoot. What a problem.
2 things: Fix the MUX rate (over the RIGHT side parameters over "Packet size") Should read 32000.

Second: Do you need to compress to divx? That´s a format no one is using anymore because of security reasons:

Use Mp4 with an .h264 wrapper. Quicktime.

Thank you if you vote me up as answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: i tried a bunch of different combinations and none of them seem to work, probably im doing something wrong with my compositing

Answer (score 0):

This was probably a bug and was solved:

[#65803 - MPEG4 unsupported timebase denominator - blender - Blender Projects](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/65803)

But if you meet such an issue today:

1. report it as bug via the menu Help > Report A Bug
2. seriously consider rendering into a sequence of image and send it to your favorite video editing software later, rather than rendering into a video file from Blender. It's a lot more flexible and foolproof anyway.